# Can I log data in file system using microsoft extension logging in asp.net core without using trird party logger

Tags: logging

I am new in logging . Can I log data in file system using Microsoft extension logging in asp.net core without using third party logger.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The built-in logging providers that come with asp.net core do not provide the ability to log to the filesystem. [ASP.NET Core Built-in logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bilp)

To log to the file system you will need to use one of the third party logging providers such as SeriLog, [List of Third Party logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#third-party-logging-providers)